# Getting Github source with cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl, github

When I try to get source code with cURL, it returns nothing in $data. But file_get_contents works fine. I have tried with adding USERAGENT, but same result. Here is my Code:

```
$url = "https://github.com/login";

$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$data = curl_exec($handle);
//$data = file_get_contents($url);

echo $data;
```

But I need to to get source by cURL. How can I do this ?

Comment: Do you want to download complete source or you want to get content of single file.

Comment: I want to get full source code. @SahilGulati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there were problem with SSL issue.

I was always getting false on `curl_exec($handle);` For this I use this code

```
if (FALSE === $data)
    throw new Exception(curl_error($handle), curl_errno($handle));
```

to debug. Then it return this Message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate in . .

Then I just add this line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

and its works fine now.